# ListView display nothing in android

Tags: android

I am implementing a `ListView` using `Custom Adapter`. I have fetch all the `SMS` from inbox and store all the information into `ArrayList` and Bind to `ListView`.I have successfully print all the `SMS` details into logcat and store into `ArrayList` but I don't know why my `ListView` displays Nothing.

There is no any error found into logcat. I saw you my code adapter code as below.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private static ArrayList data,contactid;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public ListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList b,ArrayList c) {
    activity = a;
    data = b;
    contactid=c;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowdata;
    if (convertView == null)
        rowdata = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row); // title
    String song = data.get(position).toString();
    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song);    

    return convertView;

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `rowdata`

```
 return rowdata;
```

Instead of `convertView`

```
return convertView;
```

in `getView(....)` into your `ListAdapter`:

Comment: you should use the convertView, since you are checking it for null anyway, no need to rename it 2-3 times in one method. just makes a mess out of it

Comment: let me try this way. wait

Comment: I accept your answer because you are to Quick to find my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your getView logic, you are inflating the rowdata, and returning the convertview.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row); // title
    String song = data.get(position).toString();
    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song);    

    return convertView;

}
```

besides getItem should return the Item representing the Row. You are just returning the position.

Answer (score 0):

**You just return the rowdata..**

```
View rowdata;
if (convertView == null)
    rowdata = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, null);

TextView title = (TextView) rowdata.findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row); // title
String song = data.get(position).toString();
// Setting all values in listview
title.setText(song);    

return rowdata;
```

Comment: this will probably throw nullpointers, inflating view into rowdata, looking for textview in vi, and you are only creating rowdata if convertview is null, but you are not handling the convertview at all.

Answer (score 0):

create a inner class inside your adapter like

```
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView  songTitle;
}
```

and update your getView Methode as

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
if (convertView == null){
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, null);
    viewHolder.songTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_ttlcontact_row); // title
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder); 
 }else{
  viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTeg();   
 }

 viewHolder.songTitle.setText(data.get(position).toString());

 return convertView;
}
```

also check that you getView method is getting call as many times as you array list size.hope this will solve your problem